# Подружить Python с 1С (MSSQL)

Tags: python, python-3.x, sql-server, 1с

Столкнулся с необходимостью, по запросу, выгружать из 1С(8.3) определенные данные. В начале думал просто создать в 1С регламентную задачу которая каждые 15 минут будет выгружать CSV файл со всем необходимым, но информации оказалось так много, что от этой идеи пришлось отказаться.

**Есть ли возможность научить Python обращаться к 1С (БД на MSSQL) и вытаскивать оттуда определенную информацию? В какую сторону копать?**

Comment: копать в сторону коннекта python к MSSQL серверу. Например pyodbc. А там Вы уже должны знать структуру данных и читайте запускайте что хотите

Comment: Если делать это средствами Python информации будет ещё больше. Проще разобраться с механизмами обмена 1С.

Comment: @Manul74 чем это поможет? В базе 1С автогенерированная схема мрачной структуры.

Comment: Со стандартными конфигурациями обычно идет внешняя обработка, умеющая выгружать данные в XML. Дальше уже эти данные нужно парсить. Правда, если нужно выгружать автоматически, это наверное не поможет.

Comment: *обращаться к 1С (БД на MSSQL)* надо обращаться к самой 1с? или к ее бд на mssql

Comment: Выгрузка в файл не выход. Информации так много, что только на создание файла будет потрачено минут 20. Разве что по какому-нить запросу говорить 1С файл с какими данными необходимо выгрузить в данный момент.

Comment: @Vadim.Sharoikin Мне кажется я не разберусь в структуре БД. Там 1С самописная и огромная. Проще обращаться к 1С

Comment: @ДанилКучеров `import pythoncom
import win32com.client
V83_CONN_STRING = 'File="C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\InfoBase\\";Usr="Иванов Иван";Pwd="123456";'
pythoncom.CoInitialize()
V83 = win32com.client.Dispatch("V83.COMConnector").Connect(V83_CONN_STRING)` как-нибудь так установить соединение через ком порт и дальше уже что-то делать

Comment: но думаю проще разбираться в 1с